# Export dynamic name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Suppose we have to export a large amount of names.

```
export const fn0 = fn.bind(null, '0');
export const fn1 = fn.bind(null, '1');
...
export const fn999 = fn.bind(null, '999');
```

Is it possible to export dynamic names like the following?

```
// array is [0 to 999]
array.forEach(i => export const [`fn${i}`] = fn.bind(null, i.toString());
```

Comment: Not without `eval`, why don't you just export an object with those named properties?

Comment: Or better yet, just create a function that calls your `fn` with `i`

Comment: If I export an object with named props, I have to introduce the name of the object to the caller. Besides, these exports could be seperated in several files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let fnCollection = {};
function fn(){
  return "welcome js"
}
[1,2,3,4].forEach(i =>fnCollection[`fn${i}`] = fn.bind(null, i.toString()));
export default fnCollection ;
```

Comment: This is the closest resolution so far. But, what if these exports would be seperated in several files?

Comment: simply import different fnCollections from different places in to a single file. merge those collection objects using Object.assign() or es6 spread operator and export it. hope this helps you

Comment: This isn't valid syntax, so I don't know why it was marked as correct. `export fnCollection;` is a syntax error. Did you mean `export default fnCollection;`?

Answer (score 5):

Bluntly, no.  And this is by design.

The module syntax is designed to be [statically analysed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis).  This means that it can be determined which modules are required by other modules *without executing any code*.  This has huge benefits in so-called ["tree shaking"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_shaking) where code can be selectively imported based on what is actually used (and this feature is used by module bundlers such as [rollup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_mirror) and [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/])).

This is the key way in which ES6 modules differ from [commonjs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS).  If you `require` a method from a library everything in the file is run, not only what you use.  If you `import` a function from a library you (should) only get that function.  You cannot do that if you have to run all of the code in order to find out what is exported.

to quote from [here](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_modules)

> ECMAScript 6 gives you the best of both worlds: The synchronous syntax
>   of Node.js plus the asynchronous loading of AMD. To make both
>   possible, ES6 modules are syntactically less flexible than Node.js
>   modules: Imports and exports must happen at the top level. That means
>   that they can’t be conditional, either. This restriction allows an ES6
>   module loader to analyze statically what modules are imported by a
>   module and load them before executing its body.

Comment: Any approximate solution?

Comment: As @Boobalan's solution below.  Just export one object with everything in it.